# File read and processing using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I have a massive file which is nothing but repeated units of such blocks:

```
//WAYNE ROONEY (wr10)
  90 [label="90"];
  90 -> 11 [weight=25];
  90 -> 21 [weight=23];
  90 -> 31 [weight=17];
  90 -> 41 [weight=12];
  90 -> 51 [weight=1];
  90 -> 62 [weight=50];
  90 -> 72 [weight=7];
  90 -> 82 [weight=27];
  90 -> 92 [weight=9];
  90 -> 102 [weight=43];
```

I need to convert in into a format that looks like this

```
90 11 25
```

i.e. i just need to remove all the extra stuff and just keep the number exactly the way they are.

I tried using regex, with this line of code:

```
for line in filein:
    match = re.search('label=" "', line)
    if match:
        print (match.group())
```

But it just prints all the instances of `'label'` in the file. If i try to search for `'label=" "'`, there is no output. If i could some how read the labels then reading the weights will be pretty similar to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
import re

file = open("file","r")                       

for line in file:                                 
    if re.search('->',line):
        print ' '.join(re.findall('[0-9]+',line))
```

Output:

```
90 11 25
90 21 23
90 31 17
90 41 12
90 51 1
90 62 50
90 72 7
90 82 27
90 92 9
90 102 43
```

Just redirect to save the output: `python test.py > newfile`

Answer (score 2):

You can match all lines with something like:

1. `(\d+)` -> A number (backreference)
2. `\s*->\s*` -> Space -> space
3. `(\d+)` -> Another number (backreference)
4. `\s*\[weight=\"` -> Space and the literal [weigth="
5. `(\d+)` -> Another number (backreference)
6. `\];` -> Literal ]; to end the match.

Then you have a numbered backreferences like this:

1. The first number
2. The second number
3. The third number

Now you can build your string with the pattern you want. ($1 $2 $3)

Answer (score 1):

To get all the numbers from each line, use `r'\d+'` together with `.findall()`:

```
for line in filein:
    if 'label' in line:
        print 'label:',
    print ' '.join(re.findall(r'\d', line))
```

It is not entirely clear what you want to do with the `label` lines, but the very simple loop would print out:

```
label: 90 90
90 11 25
90 21 23
90 31 17
```

etc.

Comment: The label are the nodes. The node ( 90) is connected to 11 and the weight of that edge is 25. I was planning to read through the file for all 'labels'.

Comment: @begin.py: it's easy enough to detect the string `label`, updated.